# What is the best way to cache result of a LINQ to XML query that uses anonymous types? How to Cast the cache object?

Tags: asp.net, caching, linq-to-xml, extension-methods

I am using a Gridview with paging enabled. I bind the girdview in Page_Load event using LINQ to XML.

The code looks like this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {            
        if (Cache["grid"] == null)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/CarRentalAddress.xml"));
            var grid = (from d in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() orderby d.Field<string>("City") where d.Field<string>("Enabled") == "1" select new { City = d.Field<string>("City"), HotelName = d.Field<string>("HotelName"), Address = d.Field<string>("Address"), EmailID1 = d.Field<string>("EmailID1"), EmailID2 = d.Field<string>("EmailID2") }).ToList();
            Cache["grid"] = grid;
            totalrows = grid.Count().ToString();
            grdAddress.DataSource = grid;
            grdAddress.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            var grid = Cache["grid"];
            //Extension method Count() is not working here
            totalrows = grid.Count().ToString();
            grdAddress.DataSource = grid;
            grdAddress.DataBind();
        }
        } 
    }
```

The extension method Count() in Else part of the code is not working. i want to know the best way to cast the cache object so that Extension methods and all LINQ stuffs works.

Comment: Instead of storing result in anonymous type you can store the result in strongly typed class,and then stored the strongly typed class in cache.

Comment: If you need some code for that let me know.

Comment: i tried that also. How to make all LINQ extension methods to work with my class objects?

Answer (score 0):

For demo purpose I have created a XML file in the root of website ,something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>F1</FirstName>
    <LastName>L1</LastName>
    <Age>31</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>F2</FirstName>
    <LastName>L2</LastName>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>F3</FirstName>
    <LastName>L3</LastName>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Cache["grid"]== null)
            {

                var grid = (from d in GetData().Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            orderby d.Field<string>("FirstName")
                            where d.Field<string>("Age") == "31"
                            select new Person()
                            {
                                FirstName = d.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                                LastName = d.Field<string>("LastName"),
                                Age = d.Field<string>("Age")

                            }).ToList();

                Cache["grid"] = grid;
                int totalrows = grid.Count();

                GridView1.DataSource = grid;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                var grid = (List<Person>)Cache["grid"];
                //Extension method Count() is not working here
                int totalrows = grid.Count();
                GridView1.DataSource = grid;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }

    public static DataSet GetData()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Person.xml"));
        return ds;

    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there anyway the same can be done for Anonymous types? I can not keep on defining classes for each LINQ query i use in my project.

Comment: I am not sure about this.Please check this link http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html

Comment: Error details:[A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CarRentalAddress] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CarRentalAddress]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

Comment: When i cast the Cache object back to List of CarRentalAddress type. i get the above Exception

Comment: You are talking about my code or the code u have implemented.

Comment: I am getting error in my code. i have posted my code in below link                                           http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/6b16d4c7-4e9d-47a1-8baf-02b9b680e8c4